# RANKX issues using DAX

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax

I was working on the conversion of a sql request into a dax one :

```
    >;WITH cte
    >AS
    >(
    >       SELECT uc.idU_Email
    >              ,uc.id_Type
    >              ,uc.dRecueil
    >              ,valeur
    >              ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY idU_Email,id_Type ORDER BY dRecueil DESC, valeur ASC) AS rang
    >       FROM   vUE uc 
    >       WHERE uc.Id_Type=1  AND uc.dRecueil<=(DATEADD(month, -1, GETDATE())) 
    >)                   
    >SELECT COUNT(idU_Email)
    >    FROM   cte
    >    WHERE  rang = 1 
    >    and valeur = 1
```

If i understood well, the equivalent of the rownumber function in sql in the RANKX Function in DAX. 
So basically, to achieve the conversion i created a new calculated colum with the following expression :

[Ranking on partition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mUAAU.png)

To resume it,  it makes a ranking on every parition of idU_Email order by dRecueil and then by valeur.

Thus, the only thing left to do was to add a condition on the date (like in my SQL request), but i guess i don't really know how (or where?), and an error occurred when i tried, which i haven't achieved to solved yet :

[Ranking on partition with filter on date](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5qBfA.png)

I hope someone would find a way to solve that issue (or even to propose me a better way to have the equivalent of my SQL request).

Thanks by advance ! Smiley Happy

[UPDATE]

I've achieved to partition as I wanted to do and to apply a date filter like that :

```
RANK_OnDate = IF(vUE[dRecueil] <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()); MONTH(TODAY())-1; DAY(TODAY()))
            ;RANKX(FILTER(vUE; vUE[idU_Email] = EARLIER(vUE[idU_Email]) && vUE[id_Type] = EARLIER(vUE[id_Type]))
                ;RANKX(ALL(vUE); vUE[dRecueil]; ;ASC) 
                +
                DIVIDE(
                    RANKX(ALL(vUE); vUE[valeur]; ; DESC; Skip)
                    ;COUNTROWS(ALL(vUE)) + 1
                )
            )
        )
```

But, actually, i would like it to filter dynamically... Thus i don't know if it would be better to use that directly in a measure (according that i want to count distinctly the lower/higher rank for each idU_email).

Additionally my filter just apply blank when the date isn't ok with the filter but the ranking stay the same...

I tried to do directly the distinct count in a measure but can't save the different issues encountered... Have you got some ideas ?

(and thanks for your answers) :)

Comment: What are you filtering on that you need to to be dynamic? How do you want the measure to act "when the date isn't ok with the filter"?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're pretty close, try this

```
Rank = IF(vUE[dRecueil] <= DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY())-1, DAY(TODAY())),
           RANKX(FILTER(vUE, vUE[idU_Email] = EARLIER(vUE[idU_Email])),
               RANKX(ALL(vUE), vUE[dRecueil], ,ASC) +
               DIVIDE(
                   RANKX(ALL(vUE), vUE[valeur], , DESC, Skip),
                   COUNTROWS(ALL(vUE)) + 1)))
```

Comment: It does works indeed but if that's possible i would like to apply this filter dynamically. Should i apply this in a measure directly (and how? )

Comment: You can probably convert it to a measure with some minor changes. You'd need to give more detail on how exactly you'd want it to work though. (Probably as a new question rather than changing your ask here.)

Comment: Alright if that's necessary ! :)

To resume i would like in a measure (like the sql request does) to :
"Distinctcount" the last idu_email (so rank 1 basically if a rankx is needeed) with dRecueil being inferior to a measure for each partition partitioned.  
The partition beeing both by idu_email and by id_type, and ordering by dRecueil and valeur.